# Typing dynamic object references

Tags: typescript

I have an index file for my `assets` folder that has grouped image exports like following one

```
// assets/index.ts
export const UI_ELEMENTS = {
  BUTTON_BLUE_ACTIVE: require("./button_blue_active.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_DISABLED: require("./button_blue_disabled.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_HOVER: require("./button_blue_hover.png")
}
```

I then proceed to use this like in some of my files

```
import { UI_ELEMENTS } from "./assets/index.ts"

const buttonImage = UI_ELEMENTS[`BUTTON_BLUE_${variant}`]
```

As you can see variant is dynamic i.e can be `ACTIVE` `DISABLED` or `HOVER` depending on circumstances.

I get following type error for `buttonImage`

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{
>   BUTTON_BLUE_ACTIVE: any; BUTTON_BLUE_DISABLED: any; BUTTON_BLUE_HOVER: any; }' has no index
>   signature. [7017]

I'm trying to figure out how I should type my `UI_ELEMENTS` in order to keep auto completion active and get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic property name doesn't allow the TypeScript compiler to infer the type of the accessed property.

However, `any` is fine in your case, because it is the returned type of your `require("./xxx.png")`, so `any` is the correct type of `buttonImage`. You just need to disable the error message while keeping autocompletion. I suggest three ways:

## 1. Configure the compiler to be less strict

The easier way is just to disable the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option.

## 2. Or, manually define the type of `UI_ELEMENTS`, as an [index type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) plus its properties

```
type UiElementsType = {
  [name: string]: any
  BUTTON_BLUE_ACTIVE: any,
  BUTTON_BLUE_DISABLED: any,
  BUTTON_BLUE_HOVER: any
}

const UI_ELEMENTS: UiElementsType = {
  BUTTON_BLUE_ACTIVE: require("./button_blue_active.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_DISABLED: require("./button_blue_disabled.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_HOVER: require("./button_blue_hover.png")
}
```

This is the declarative solution. This example is not DRY, you have to write each property name twice. But maybe could you dynamically fill the `UI_ELEMENTS` object, using the fact that the property name in upper case is the same as the file name in lower case?

## 3. Or, use a helper to infer the type

```
function asIndexType<T>(obj: T): T & { [name: string]: any } {
  return obj
}

const UI_ELEMENTS = asIndexType({
  BUTTON_BLUE_ACTIVE: require("./button_blue_active.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_DISABLED: require("./button_blue_disabled.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_HOVER: require("./button_blue_hover.png")
})
```

Here we declare a helper `asIndexType` that infers the same type as in the solution 2. This is DRY but the helper `asIndexType` will remain in the compiled code whereas it is unnecessary at runtime.

Comment: You should really be suggesting the third option first. That's the best one. One should not encourage disabling `--noImplicitAny` and you should apply any only at the level needed

Comment: @JuanMendes I personally prefer the two first options because I dislike unnecessary code pollution. But it is a matter of taste. ;-)

Comment: By code pollution, you mean type information? Then why use TS?

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry but I disagree. When the implicit type `any` is the correct type, TypeScript annotations don't provide useful information.

Comment: Allowing implicit any will cause people to be lazy and not type things they should and only use any when absolutely necessary

Comment: Option 3 is best solution, keeps autocomplete and fixes the error, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you should be explicitly marking each object as any. Avoid the temptation to start using `--noImplicitAny` which would get rid of the message.

```
export const UI_ELEMENTS = {
  BUTTON_BLUE_ACTIVE: require("./button_blue_active.png") as any,
  BUTTON_BLUE_DISABLED: require("./button_blue_disabled.png") as any,
  BUTTON_BLUE_HOVER: require("./button_blue_hover.png") as any
}
```

Or you could use a little more type safety with the following which enforces that all objects are of the same type in a literal like you have (except that since they are any, that part doesn't help much in your case. You still get type completion using the following:

```
export type ObjectOf<T> = { [k: string]: T };

/**
 * Allows you to enforce that an object's properties are all of the same type and creates a type safe object that you
 * get auto complete for.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * const Ab = createObjectOf<number>({a: true}); // Compile error
 *
 * const Ab = createObjectOf<number>({a: 1, b: 2});
 * Ab.a.toFixed() (with autocompletion)
 */
export function createObjectOf<TValue>() {
    return function <T extends ObjectOf<TValue>>(v: T) {
        return v;
    };
}

export const UI_ELEMENTS = createObjectOf<any>()({
  BUTTON_BLUE_ACTIVE: require("./button_blue_active.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_DISABLED: require("./button_blue_disabled.png"),
  BUTTON_BLUE_HOVER: require("./button_blue_hover.png")
})
```

Comment: You don't answer to the question. The properties of `UI_ELEMENTS` already have the `any` type.

Comment: And the `createObjectOf` helper doesn't make the error message disappear.

Comment: @Paleo But at least the parts that are known use types. You get auto complete for the property names of UI_ELEMENTS instead of marking it any at that level. It does make the error disappear in my tests